# Laravel 8.X select all record with latest status

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have 2 model in relationship

**Tickets** model

```
public function status(){ return $this->hasMany(Status::class); }
public function latestStatus(){ return $this->hasOne(Status::class)->latest();}
```

**Status** model

```
public function tickets(){ $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class);}
```

I am trying to get the latest status of each tickets using this code

```
public function scopeFilteredStatus($query){ 
 return $query->whereHas('latestStatus',function($status){ 
  $status->whereIn('status', ['status1,'status3','status6']);
})->get(); }
```

what ive got

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1609 ▼
  #items: array:302 [▶]
}
```

was expecting a fewer result

```
id --- user_id --- ticket_id --- status --- created_at
xx --- 10001   --- 3100      --- status1 --- 2020-01-13
xx --- 10001   --- 3200      --- status3 --- 2020-01-09
xx --- 10004   --- 2900      --- status6 --- 2020-01-20
and more...
```

Comment: The output from your code isn't clear enough to match with the expected output can you please update your question and tell us what exactly is the issue

Comment: my issue is i cannot get it to work

Answer (score 1):

remove `get()` in your scope:

```
public function scopeFilteredStatus($query){ 
 return $query->whereHas('latestStatus',function($status){ 
  $status->whereIn('status', ['status1,'status3','status6']);
})->get(); }
```

to

```
public function scopeFilteredStatus($query){ 
 return $query->whereHas('latestStatus',function($status){ 
  $status->whereIn('status', ['status1,'status3','status6']);
}) }
```

now try this: `Ticket::filteredStatus()->get()`